# Error printing with Canon ir1435 Idle - Filter failed

Tags: 16.04, printing, canon

Driver: cque-en-3.0-5 from [Canon drivers](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/products/imagerunner/imagerunner-1435i.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)) 64bits

When I try to print form the printer properties 'Print Self-Test Page' the printer works but it does not work when 'Print Test Page'.

```
Printer state: Idle - Filter failed
```

**/var/log/cups/error_log**

```
D [05/Jul/2017:08:59:49 +0200] [Job 12] /bin/sh: 1: sicgsfilter: not found
D [05/Jul/2017:08:59:49 +0200] [Job 12] renderer exited with status 127
D [05/Jul/2017:08:59:49 +0200] [Job 12] Kid3 exit status: 1
D [05/Jul/2017:08:59:49 +0200] [Job 12] PID 8999 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/foomatic-rip) stopped with status 9.
D [05/Jul/2017:08:59:49 +0200] [Job 12] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [05/Jul/2017:08:59:49 +0200] [Job 12] PID 9000 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/socket) exited with no errors.
D [05/Jul/2017:08:59:49 +0200] [Job 12] End of messages
D [05/Jul/2017:08:59:49 +0200] [Job 12] printer-state=3(idle)
D [05/Jul/2017:08:59:49 +0200] [Job 12] printer-state-message="Filter failed"
D [05/Jul/2017:08:59:49 +0200] [Job 12] printer-state-reasons=none
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create the following link

```
ln -s /opt/cel/bin/sicgsfilter /bin/sicgsfilter
```

It seems the driver didn't make it.

Comment: I wondered which driver you used: I see Canon supply the UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux V3.31 that is a recent release: 14th April 2017 and one downloads linux-UFRII-drv-v331-uken.tar.gz from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100270810.html and inside that is an install.sh script that does driver install and printer registration for lpadmin; that latest release tidied up a dependency issue in the 3.30 version

Comment: This is the driver I used cque-en-3.0-5

Comment: gosh; where does that come from; you could also download the package from Canon; and install that; best to rename the cque driver so you can recognise it as different from the proper Canon one; the commands to install the Canon if you download to your Downloads directory; in french it is telechargements? ne c'est pas? `cd Downloads` then `tar -zxvf linux-UFRII-drv-v331-uken.tar.gz` then `cd linux-UFRII-drv-v331-uken` and then `./install.sh` and that will run the Canon install script;

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I just download the driver for my printer from canon web page and I got that error. Here I leave the link http://www.canon-europe.com/support/products/imagerunner/imagerunner-1435i.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit). Is the driver you refer to a generic one?

Comment: you are right; Canon Europe recommend the cqe; Canon Asia; that I normally look up; recommend the UFR; you could also install it; to evaluate it; you should have the option as it is being installed of selecting a name: if you added UFR or such; then  you could recognise it; from the CQE driver

Comment: Sorry to revive this, but I have the same problem with the same error (down to the PID numbers) and the link is present in my system. Any other thing I could try?